# How to add a button to all posts in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, backend, code-snippets, custom-code

I have created a button using wordpress block editor. I have linked this button to a section. I need this button to be present in the beginning of all my posts.How can I automate it rather than having to make it again and again? I am currently using the jnews theme

I tried installing code snippets but I don't know the right php code to enable this. If anyone could provide the code it would be a great help..

Answer (score 0):

You should edit single post template.

Its path for example is "/wp-content/themes/your_theme/single.php".

Place HTML code of the button to this file.